Usign csrf token In chrome I get: "Puma caught this error: decoded token is not valid for request method and path". But it works fine on Firefox
I'm developing a site using Roda with the route_csrf plugin and Puma as the application server for Ruby.
In all post request I get the next error in Chrome and Edge. On Firefox I don't get the error, everything works fine
Puma caught this error: decoded token is not valid for request method and path (Roda::RodaPlugins::RouteCsrf::InvalidToken)
This is an example of the loging form
"
<%== csrf_tag ("/login") %>"
I guess Chrome and Edge are changing the path of the csrf token cookie while Firefox is not, but I don't know how to configure Chrome and Edge to avoid that
Could the problem be something else?
I appreciate any help, thanks
I configured another server with the app implementing SSL, thinking Chrome and Edge does not send cookies over http but https, but that did not fixed the problem
